# 'list' object has no attribute 'text' en xml.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

Estoy ejecutando el siguiente código para la modificación de un valor de un archivo xml

```
for i in range(n):
    cohesion = c[i]
    cohesion_new  = root.findall(".//*Material[@ID='{}']/Parameters/c".format(id_material))
    cohesion_new.text = str(cohesion)
```

pero me arroja el error: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'.

también probé con

```
for i in range(n):
    cohesion = str(c[i])
    cohesion_new  = root.findall(".//*Material[@ID='{}']/Parameters/c".format(id_material))
    cohesion_new.text = cohesion
```

Si ejecuto root.findall() fuera del ciclo for se modifica sin problemas. Sin embargo, necesito hacer la modificación a partir de los elementos de la lista.

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `findall` devuelve una lista. Las listas no tiene atributo `text`.

**findall(match, namespaces=None)**

> Encuentra todos los sub-elementos coincidentes, por nombre de etiqueta
> o path. **Retorna una lista** que contiene todos los elementos
> coincidentes en el orden del documento. namespaces es un mapeo
> opcional del prefijo del espacio de nombres al nombre completo. Pasa
> '' como prefijo para mover todos los nombres de etiquetas sin prefijo
> en la expresión al espacio de nombres dado.